# Combine data from previous week with current week in R

Tags: r

Hi I have a dataframe given below

```
s.no week number   Income
1     6            52 
2     7            74 
3     8            13 
4     9            60
```

I need this dataframe to be changed with an addition of a new column Total_income having the formula -

```
 100% value of Income in current week + 
  60% value of income in previous week + 
  30% value of income in previous to previous week
```

Output should be like -

```
s.no week number Income Total_Income
 1      6          52      52
 2      7          74      74+0.6(52)=105.2
 3      8          13      13+0.6(74)+0.3(52) = 73
 4      9          60      60+0.6(13)+0.3(74) = 90
```

Kindly help

Comment: is the data always ordered by week number, ie. the values in week number column will always be sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dataframe `data` is ordered by week number. If not, begin with `data %>% arrange(week_number) %>%` (note column renamed to remove space).

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(Total_Income = Income + 0.6 * lag(Income, default = 0) + 
         0.3 * lag(Income, n = 2, default = 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

The base R option with `sapply`. For every value in `week_number` we find the `Income` for that week, along with previous two weeks and sum them together with necessary arithmetic.

```
with(df, sapply(week_number, function(x) { sum(Income[week_number == x], 
  0.6 * Income[week_number == x-1], 0.3 *Income[week_number == x-2])
}))

#[1]  52.0 105.2  73.0  90.0
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table` and do this in a single line

```
library(data.table)
setDT(d)[,Total_Income := Reduce(`+`, Map(`*`,shift(Income,n=0:2,fill=0), c(1, 0.6, 0.3)))]
d
#   s.no weeknumber Income Total_Income
#1:    1          6     52         52.0
#2:    2          7     74        105.2
#3:    3          8     13         73.0
#4:    4          9     60         90.0
```

---

Or we can do a cross product

```
c(crossprod(do.call(rbind, shift(d$Income, n = 0:2, fill = 0)), c(1, 0.6, 0.3)))
#[1]  52.0 105.2  73.0  90.0
```